# Multiple REGEXREPLACE in google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, replace, substitution

i want to replace 3 caracters in one string

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(A5,"c","a"); REGEXREPLACE(A5,"d","x");REGEXREPLACE(A5,"v","y")})
```

is possible?
I want to add it to a query on future too :D
ty alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be like:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A5,"c","a"), "d","x"), "v","y")))
```

for array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A5:A,"c","a"), "d","x"), "v","y"))))
```